# How to prevent old versions of C# dlls from running

Tags: c#, .net, dll, versioning

I have a Library Projects that gets used in a variety of other Programs and I want to prevent old versions of the Library to run. Is it possible to include a code snippet that gets called every time the dll is being loaded?

Or do you have any other idea how to prevent older versions from being called in programs?

To be more precise I want to prevent future old versions from running, older versions that are being used right now can not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

You can define that in the config file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
                          publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect  oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

That way, whenever you have an assembly that matches that identity, the framework will use that other version you provided.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I don't have control over some programs calling the library, is there a way to set this in the dll itself ?

Comment: You can create a YourAssembly.dll.config, put it in the same directory of the other files and give it a try